# Como faço para as piranhas geradas aleatoriamente se moverem até a hélice? UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom eu preciso que as piranhas criadas aleatoriamente se movam na direção da helice e no contato causem um dano (reduzindo a vida do player).

esse é o codigo do spawn com localidade aleatoria.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class piranhaSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject piranhaMon;
    public float xPos;
    public float yPos;
    public int piranhaCount;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PiranhaSpawn());
    }

    IEnumerator PiranhaSpawn() {
        while (piranhaCount < 6)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(7.2f, 13f);
            yPos = Random.Range(-3f, 3f);
            Instantiate(piranhaMon, new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.6f);
            piranhaCount += 1;
            
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: No seu `Update()` você não deveria movimentá-las?

Answer (score 0):

Moid tera3, para fazer com que um gameObject se mova até outro você pode criar um script e atribuir a cada piranha, nele você referencia a helice e usa a função [MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) para fazer ele ir até o objeto. Caso for um jogo 2D (pelo que eu entendi do código, acho que é) você pode olhar a função para [Vector2 do MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html), mas a ideia é essencialmente a mesma.

Peguei esse código da própria documentação da Unity e adaptei.

```cs
public class Piranha : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 HeliceTransform;

    private float speed = 10.0f;
    private Vector2 target;
 
    void Update()
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        // move sprite towards the target location
        transform.position = 
               Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, HeliceTransform.position, step);
    }
}
```

No caso o HeliceTransform é uma propriedade pública então você pode fazer o seguinte.

Pega a referência do transform da hélice no seu código de spawn e guarda a referencia da instancia da piranha e então pega o componente Piranha e atribui o transform da hélice. Assim:

```cs
public class piranhaSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform HeliceTransform; // REFERENCIA PARA A HELICE
    public GameObject piranhaMon;
    public float xPos;
    public float yPos;
    public int piranhaCount;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PiranhaSpawn());
    }

    IEnumerator PiranhaSpawn() {
        while (piranhaCount < 6)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(7.2f, 13f);
            yPos = Random.Range(-3f, 3f);
            GameObject piranhaObj; // ARMAZENA A INSTANCIA DA PIRANHA NESSA VAR
            piranhaObj = Instantiate(piranhaMon, new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            // ATRIBUI O VALOR DO TRANSFORM HELICE NA PIRANHA
            piranhaObj.GetComponent<Piranha>().HeliceTransform = HeliceTransform;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.6f);
            piranhaCount += 1;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Os códigos podem precisar de uma revisão, mas a ideia é essa. Espero ter lhe dado um norte e ajudado de alguma forma.

Recomendo fortemente que faça um tutorial para iniciantes, há vários vídeos gratuitos no youtube ensinando ou se já tem conhecimento em programação, dar uma lida na [documentação](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html) sempre que estiver em dúvida.